# GeneratedValue is being generated in local dev environment, but not in the production environment on platform.sh (Symfony 6.1)

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

The value:

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CompanyRepository::class)]
class Company
{
  #[ORM\Id]
  #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
  #[ORM\Column]
  private ?int $id = null;
```

The code:

```
dump($company);
dump($entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions() );

$entityManager->persist($company);
dump($company);
dump($entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions() );

$entityManager->persist($user);
dump($entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions() );
die();

$entityManager->flush();
```

Output in local dev env:

```
RegistrationController.php on line 65:
App\Entity\Company {#1258 ▼
  -id: null
  -comment: null
  -employees: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#1029 ▶}
  -addresses: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#1488 ▶}
  -orders: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#1232 ▶}
  -ustnr: null
  -name: "test12333"
}
RegistrationController.php on line 66:
[]
RegistrationController.php on line 68:
App\Entity\Company {#1258 ▼
  -id: 5
  -comment: null
  -employees: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#1029 ▶}
  -addresses: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#1488 ▶}
  -orders: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#1232 ▶}
  -ustnr: null
  -name: "test12333"
}
RegistrationController.php on line 69:
array:1 [▼
  1258 => App\Entity\Company {#1258 ▶}
]
RegistrationController.php on line 71:
array:2 [▼
  1258 => App\Entity\Company {#1258 ▶}
  876 => App\Entity\User {#876 ▶}
]
```

Output on platform.sh:

```
^ App\Entity\Company {#914 ▼
  -id: null
  -comment: null
  -employees: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#637 ▶}
  -addresses: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#913 ▶}
  -orders: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#835 ▶}
  -ustnr: null
  -name: "test1232"
}
^ []
^ App\Entity\Company {#914 ▼
  -id: null
  -comment: null
  -employees: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#637 ▶}
  -addresses: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#913 ▶}
  -orders: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#835 ▶}
  -ustnr: null
  -name: "test1232"
}
^ array:1 [▼
  914 => App\Entity\Company {#914 ▶}
]
^ array:2 [▼
  914 => App\Entity\Company {#914 ▶}
  469 => App\Entity\User {#469 ▶}
]
```

As you see, locally I have Company::id generated after $em->persist($company), but in the cloud it stays null.

If we remove the debug code, then we get the following error, but only on platform.sh:

```
{"message":"Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\NotNullConstraintViolationException: \"An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column \"id\" of relation \"company\" violates not-null constraint\nDETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, null, Test123).\" at /app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/API/PostgreSQL/ExceptionConverter.php line 47","context":{"exception":{"class":"Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\NotNullConstraintViolationException","message":"An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column \"id\" of relation \"company\" violates not-null constraint\nDETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, null, Test123).","code":7,"file":"/app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/API/PostgreSQL/ExceptionConverter.php:47","previous":{"class":"Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDO\\Exception","message":"SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column \"id\" of relation
 \"company\" violates not-null constraint\nDETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, null, Test123).","code":7,"file":"/app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/PDO/Exception.php:28","previous":{"class":"PDOException","message":"SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR:  null value in column \"id\" of relation \"company\" violates not-null constraint\nDETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, null, Test123).","code":23502,"file":"/app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/PDO/Statement.php:121"}}}},"level":500,"level_name":"CRITICAL","channel":"request","datetime":"2023-05-09T12:08:20.446581+00:00","extra":{}}
```

The database server version (PostgreSQL 14.7) is equal in both environments, and, I suppose, the schema is also equal -- it is being created by automatic application of all migrations.

How can I debug the problem further and find out the reason for this strange behaviour?

UPDATE

The command outputs a series of operations consisting of multiple repetitions of the following sequence for different tables: CREATE SEQUENCE ... SELECT setval(... ALTER TABLE ... The one relevant, I guess, is the following:

```
web@app.0:~$ bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql | grep company       

CREATE SEQUENCE company_id_seq;SELECT setval('company_id_seq', (SELECT  MAX(id) FROM company));     ALTER TABLE company ALTER id SET DEFAULT nextval('company_id_seq');
```

Locally it is:

```
symfony console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql    

[WARNING] Not passing the "--complete" option to "orm:schema-tool:update" is deprecated and will not be supported when            using doctrine/dbal 4     

[OK] Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.
```

What would be the right way to fix the difference?

```
doctrine:schema:update
```

Comment: Please share the DDL from both environments and the SQL that resulted in the error message. Something is different, but we can't see it without access.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide result of `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` on platform sh.

It look like there is a sequence on each id on your local database and not on prod database.

Also if a developer delete and recreate migration on local, if they delete tables manually, sequence are kept.

So any new migration generated for those tables will not contain the creation of sequence.

Also i advise you to use `#[ORM\GeneratedValue('IDENTITY')]` for ids which will be the default value in next DBAL version.
So when ids are created on pgsql database, it will use `SERIAL` keyword insted of `INT` with a separated query to create a sequence (try it).

Example of what it will do:

```
CREATE TABLE table (id SERIAL NOT NULL)
```

INSTEAD OF

```
CREATE SEQUENCE table_id_seq INCREMENT BY 1 MINVALUE 1 START 1;
CREATE TABLE table (id INT NOT NULL)
```

----------- Updated answer after comment -----------

So, as i though you do not have sequence in your prod environment.
There is two way to fix that.

```
doctrine:schema:update
```

But in my view, this is too dangerous.
The second way, is also the proper way to make change on database on production environment. Dump your prod database to your local env. Because your local database seems irelevant.

https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/current/index.html

It is always in two step :

```
doctrine:migrations:diff
```

Will generate a file with all the queries needed to sync your database.
Then you can look at its content to be sure it is good and dosnt change other things that those you needed.
Anyway anything inside will need to be done one day but lets focus on your sequence problem.
Each time you see this combo of three queries, you can let it.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE company_id_seq; // Create the sequence
SELECT setval('company_id_seq', (SELECT  MAX(id) FROM company)); // Set the sequence to the max id of the table we will link      
ALTER TABLE company ALTER id SET DEFAULT nextval('company_id_seq'); // link the table to the sequence
```

If you see those 3 queries for other tables. i advise you to fix them also.

Then when you migration file only contain what you need.
Execute :

```
doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

At least your sequence issue will be fix. But keep in mind a doctrine:migration:diff must be empty. It mean your database is in sync with your entity.

Comment: The command outputs a series of operations consisting of multiple repetitions of the following sequence for different tables:
CREATE SEQUENCE ...
SELECT setval(...
ALTER TABLE ...

The one relevant, I guess, is the following:

`web@app.0:~$ bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql | grep company


    CREATE SEQUENCE company_id_seq;SELECT setval('company_id_seq', (SELECT  MAX(id) FROM company));
    ALTER TABLE company ALTER id SET DEFAULT nextval('company_id_seq');
`

Comment: Locally it is: `symfony console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql


 [WARNING] Not passing the "--complete" option to "orm:schema-tool:update" is deprecated and will not be supported when
           using doctrine/dbal 4



 [OK] Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.`

Comment: What would be the right way to fix the difference? `bin/console doctrine:schema:update` in the cloud?

Comment: please provide what u put in comment to your original question. Just edit it. It will help me read it :)

Comment: I did this, thank you for the recommendation.

Comment: @RomanReimche do you use doctrine migration ?

Comment: I use symphony migrations as you can see from my update. I guess these are also doctrine migrations.

Comment: I've updated my answer, take a look at it

Comment: I did doctrine:schema:update in production (I don't care about data there for now) and I have got new errors. After that I have created a new project at platform.sh and deployed to it. I suppose that this ways I have a pure and clean environment where I apply my migrations, but in practice I have got the same error as before.

Comment: I cannot do doctrine:migrations:diff in the cloud, because after deployment ist a read-only filesystem. Among the option of the command I don't find any that could let me output into console and --dump-sql doesn't work as well.

Comment: that's why i said dump prod database into local. So you can execute the :diff and generate the proper file. 
Then during the deploy process, execute the migrate. This is standard using symfony, i bet there is thing that already do it using platformsh

Comment: I have just clone the repo into another folder locally, created another db and applied migrations, built the project and then saw that the problem does not occur. Whereas, as described earlier, I tried basically the same with the cloud and the problem is there. Why can this be the case? The database server version is the same, as well as the migrations.

Comment: I have also checked doctrine:migrations:status locally and remotely, it's the same version.